# Add an element to a list base on the value of the list (python)

Tags: python, list, append, element

So I have a list of x elements as such:

```
list = ['0001', '0002', '0003', '0004', '0005', '0006', '0007', '0008', '0009']
```

If a element is removed (ex: '0004'):

```
['0001', '0002', '0003', '0005', '0006', '0007', '0008', '0009']
```

How can I add an element base on the last value which in this case is '0009'?

```
['0001', '0002', '0003', '0005', '0006', '0007', '0008', '0009', '0010']
```

Comment: what happens after 0099? does next value will be 0100?

Comment: @Novato : By default your value will be added at last in list ... if you are trying to add a new value

Comment: @Novato : Incase want to add in middle you can make use of `import bisect`  and use method `insort` in combination with `zfill`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just create a zero padded value adding 1 to to the numeric value at last using [`str.zfill`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.zfill), then append to the list:

```py
lst = ['0001', '0002', '0003', '0004', '0005', '0006', '0007', '0008', '0009']
print(lst.pop(3))
val = str(int(lst[-1])+1).zfill(4)
lst.append(val)
print(lst)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```py
0004
['0001', '0002', '0003', '0005', '0006', '0007', '0008', '0009', '0010']
```

Answer (score 1):

Slight modification to author code : @ThePyGuy

Just to dynamically define the padding of zero based on `'0004'`

**Code :**

```
lst = ['0001', '0002', '0003', '0004', '0005', '0006', '0007', '0008', '0009']
lng=len(str(lst[3]))
val = str(int(lst[-1])+1).zfill(lng)
lst.append(val)
print(lst)
```

Incase any issue feel free to guide me

Comment: I'll try both to see which approach helps in my case, thanks.